# Split a Bash script with ImageMagick instructions into smaller pieces?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, xargs

I have this bash script, feeding drawing information into ImageMagick, which starts like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
convert -size 2200x2200 xc:white \
-fill '#FFFEFF' -draw 'point 1112,1111' \
-fill '#FFFEFE' -draw 'point 1112,1112' \
-fill '#FFFEFE' -draw 'point 1111,1112' \
-fill '#FFFEFE' -draw 'point 1110,1112' \
-fill '#FFFEFE' -draw 'point 1110,1111' \
******ON & ON 4.2 MILLION LINES MORE*******
spectrumspiral.png;
```

My problem is I keep getting warnings about argument list too long, terminal says 'Killed', warning about 'fork: cannot allocate memory etc.

I've tried adjusting `ulimit -s` to a much higher value to no avail. Really want to make this image. Any idea how I can feed the terminal chunks of this script at a time? Or something to that end.

I've heard xargs can be used for things like this, but I haven't been able to find a specific implementation that fits the nature of this problem.

Comment: Deeply inefficient to draw so many points using the commandline like that.  If you can't use high primitives, like lines, etc, then would suggest doing it in code with something with an image magick library.

Comment: If you must do it like that, it'll take an ice age, you could probably split the points in to batches, save to a file, then continue, as there do not appear to be any complications or overwrites there.  Make sure you use a non-compressed intermediate format.

Comment: Or make a image just with the points and then somehow blend both images together

Comment: @BeniBela working on that now. creating 4 separate images each with about a million lines and then composting them.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the shell's here-document

```
#!/bin/bash 

convert - <<EOS spectrumspiral.png
-size 2200x2200 xc:white  
-fill '#FFFEFF' -draw point '1112,1111'
-fill '#FFFEFE' -draw 'point 1112,1112'
-fill '#FFFEFE' -draw 'point 1111,1112'
-fill '#FFFEFE' -draw 'point 1110,1112'
-fill '#FFFEFE' -draw 'point 1110,1111'
# ******ON & ON 4.2 MILLION LINES MORE*****
EOS
```

My system doesn't have `convert` so I can test that this works.

Most linux programs (including `convert`) can accept input from StdIn, which in the cmd-line above is represented by the `-` char. The `-` tells the command to expect input, not from file, but as if it was being typed at the keyboard, ie StdIn. The `<<EOS .... EOS` is the here-doc, and it represents bash 'typing' in all of that text into the commands stdIn input.

You may or may not need all of the quoting, if you already have there, I don't think it will hurt. If this doesn't work as is, use a small sample file of input (like above) and test various scenarios until it creates a file for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you create an image with 4 pixels in it (1 red, 1 white, 1 blue and 1 black), you can tell ImageMagick to output the resulting image as text file as follows:

```
convert -size 1x1 xc:red xc:white xc:blue xc:black +append -depth 8 -colorspace RGB image.txt

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,255,rgb
0,0: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  rgb(255,0,0)
1,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  rgb(255,255,255)
2,0: (0,0,255)  #0000FF  rgb(0,0,255)
3,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  rgb(0,0,0)
```

By the same token, if you feed that text file into ImageMagick, it can recreate the image:

```
cat image.txt | convert txt:- output.img
```

So, all we need to do is convert your `-fill` commands into a text file of the format that ImageMagick likes. So we can do this to `yourFile`

```
sed -E 's/.*(#[0-9A-F]+).* ([0-9]+)\,([0-9]+).*/\2,\3:\1/g' yourFile
```

and we will get something like this:

```
0,0:#3C4AD8
0,1:#269531
0,2:#CF2C7C
...
...
```

which we can then pipe into `awk` to rearrange how ImageMagick likes it:

```
awk -F: '
 BEGIN{print "# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 2200,2200,255,rgb"}
 {
    coords=$1;colour=$2
    rh="0x" substr(colour,2,2);
    gh="0x" substr(colour,4,2);
    bh="0x" substr(colour,6,2);
    r=strtonum(rh);
    g=strtonum(gh);
    b=strtonum(bh);
    printf "%s: (%d,%d,%d) %s\n",coords,r,g,b,colour;
 }'
```

So, if we put all that together, the following script should be able to create your beloved image into the file `spectrumspiral.png`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -E 's/.*(#[0-9A-F]+).* ([0-9]+)\,([0-9]+).*/\2,\3:\1/g' yourFile | awk -F: '
 BEGIN{print "# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 2200,2200,255,rgb"}
 {
    coords=$1;colour=$2
    rh="0x" substr(colour,2,2);
    gh="0x" substr(colour,4,2);
    bh="0x" substr(colour,6,2);
    r=strtonum(rh);
    g=strtonum(gh);
    b=strtonum(bh);
    printf "%s: (%d,%d,%d) %s\n",coords,r,g,b,colour;
 }' | convert txt:- spectrumspiral.png
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this much more simply with a *"magick script"*. Just put all your commands in a text file and invoke:

```
magick -script cmds.mgk
```

Save all your commands in a file called `cmds.mgk` in this format:

```
size 3x1 xc:black
-fill red  -draw "point 0,0"
-fill lime -draw "point 1,0"
-fill blue -draw "point 2,0"
-scale 100x
-write result.png
```

[image]