How do I format ImageMagick argument for Powershell script (array of points for drawing intersecting lines connecting hexagonal vertices)?
I'm trying to set up a project to interest nephew in design/coding (while learning myself). This snippet appears to work, but it's suboptimal and I can't figure out how to set $draw as array and call thrice like -draw $draw[i] that works (or otherwise approach). I've tried iterations of single- and/or double-quotes. (Idk how to initialize $hex properly either.)
# Hexagon
$size = '482'
$half = $size/2
$hex = @(0,1,2,3,4,5)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 6; $i++)
{
    $x = $half * [math]::cos(2 * [math]::pi * $i/6+[math]::pi) + $half
    $y = $half * [math]::sin(2 * [math]::pi * $i/6+[math]::pi) + $half
    $hex[$i] = "$x,$y"
}
$draw1 = 'line ' + $hex[0] + ' ' + $hex[3]
$draw2 = 'line ' + $hex[1] + ' ' + $hex[4]
$draw3 = 'line ' + $hex[2] + ' ' + $hex[5]
Write-Output $draw1
magick -size '482x482' xc:none -stroke 'black' -fill 'white' -draw "polygon $hex" `
-stroke 'black' -fill 'none' `
-draw $draw1 -draw $draw2 -draw $draw3 test_hex.png



I can't understand any of Microsoft's bizarre/arcane scripting (BATCH or Powershell), so my advice would be to use ImageMagick scripting which is unhindered by quoting. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77933610/2836621 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721917/400632

Yes, it's convoluted. I switched from BATCH to Powershell to handle drag-drop args, and I pass a bunch of variables to the magick command(s), so I'm kinda commited at this point.

Nah.... PowerShell works great, just gotta try harder to understand the issue to learn when you run into pitfalls as exist with all programming languages. Try setting the variables with this syntax $draw1 = "line $($hex[0]) $($hex[3])"; $draw2 = "line $($hex[1]) $($hex[4])"; $draw3 = "line $($hex[2]) $($hex[5])"; and see what happens, split your line breaks accordingly, it won't be new lines in comments so I ended each with a semi colon.

# Hexagon
$size = 482
$half = $size/2
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 6; $i++){
    $x = $half * [math]::cos(2 * [math]::pi * $i/6 + [math]::pi) + $half
    $y = $half * [math]::sin(2 * [math]::pi * $i/6 + [math]::pi) + $half
    $hex[$i] = "$x,$y"
}
$draw = @(
        '-draw', ('line', $hex[0], $hex[3] -join ' ')
        '-draw', ('line', $hex[1], $hex[4] -join ' ')
        '-draw', ('line', $hex[2], $hex[5] -join ' '))
Write-Output $draw
magick -size $size'x'$size xc:none -stroke black -fill white -draw "polygon $hex" `
-fill none `
$draw test_hex.png


You don't need to set -stroke black twice, it will remain set from the first time.

yeah, oversight. Thanks for looking
